# How can I preserve data in a container when stopping and starting it within Azure Container Service?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli

I am working on a research project on how to integrate Microsoft Business Central with other applications. 
Therefore, I have created a Windows Container 
within the Azure environment where I have deployed the image `mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox` 
as a container into an Azure Container Service.

We have created custom data within the container, but when I stop the container using the Azure CLI with "`az stop`" 
and start the container with "`az container start -g ContainerGroupName -n ContainerName`" again, all test data is lost.

The "`az start`" command seems to create a blank, new container from the image.

Is there a way to start a container within Azure Container Service, 
like the docker commands "`docker start/stop <containerid>`", so that custom data remains in the container when a container is stopped?

Comment: If you use a Linux image you can store the data in persist volume for ACI. But it doesn't support in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but the image `mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox` is only available for Windows Systems, not Linux.

Comment: Not sure, maybe you can try to mount a file share Just a advice you can try.